# WhatsApp - unable to complete initialization

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, whatsapp-messenger

I'm using sony ericsson and Android 2.3. Even though I'm connected to the internet, I keep getting this error from WhatsApp.

> Sorry, WhatsApp was unable to complete initialization. Please check
>   that you are connected to the Internet and try again.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Try follow this steps from the official whatsapp faq: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20970873

Comment: Fast forward to 2020, [WhatsApp doesn't support Android 2.3.7 or older anymore](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/21166563/).